# How to implement different sequences in shell sort in python?

Tags: python, shellsort

Hi I have the following code for implementing Shell sort in Python. How can I implement the following sequences in Shell sort using the code below (Note this is not the list I want to sort) :

1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364, 1093, 3280, 9841, 29524 (Knuth’s sequence) 
1, 5, 17, 53, 149, 373, 1123, 3371, 10111, 30341 
1, 10, 30, 60, 120, 360, 1080, 3240, 9720, 29160

```
interval = n // 2
while interval > 0:
    for i in range(interval, n):
        temp = array[i]
        j = i
        while j >= interval and array[j - interval] > temp:
            array[j] = array[j - interval]
            j -= interval

        array[j] = temp
    interval //= 2
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What's special about any of those sequences? You can sort *any* sequence using shell sort.

Comment: @chepner I want to know how I can implement the above sequences in the shell sort algorithm. I need to change the interval variable but I am unsure how?

Comment: I don't know what those sequences have to do with `interval`; that's just a value used to implement the divide-and-conquer strategy used by shell sort.  You don't *create* sequences with shell-sort; you get sequences as input and sort them.

Comment: Perhaps this may help for Knuth sequence: [How is the Knuth Sequence properly implemented for a shellsort in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339851/how-is-the-knuth-sequence-properly-implemented-for-a-shellsort-in-java)

Comment: @DarrylG thank you! this is helpful I wonder if I can use some sort of iterative approach for the other two sequences (since there is no formula like that for the Knuth sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the pseudo-code provided in the [Wikipedia article for Shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) to take in the gap sequence as a parameter:

```
from random import choices
from timeit import timeit

RAND_SEQUENCE_SIZE = 500

GAP_SEQUENCES = {
    'CIURA_A102549': [701, 301, 132, 57, 23, 10, 4, 1],
    'KNUTH_A003462': [29524, 9841, 3280, 1093, 364, 121, 40, 13, 4, 1],
    'SPACED_OUT_PRIME_GAPS': [30341, 10111, 3371, 1123, 373, 149, 53, 17, 5, 1],
    'SPACED_OUT_EVEN_GAPS': [29160, 9720, 3240, 1080, 360, 120, 60, 30, 10, 1],
}

def shell_sort(seq: list[int], gap_sequence: list[int]) -> None:
    n = len(seq)
    # Start with the largest gap and work down to a gap of 1. Similar to
    # insertion sort but instead of 1, gap is being used in each step.
    for gap in gap_sequence:
        # Do a gapped insertion sort for every element in gaps.
        # Each gap sort includes (0..gap-1) offset interleaved sorting.
        for offset in range(gap):
            for i in range(offset, n, gap):
                # Save seq[i] in temp and make a hole at position i.
                temp = seq[i]
                # Shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until the correct
                # location for seq[i] is found.
                j = i
                while j >= gap and seq[j - gap] > temp:
                    seq[j] = seq[j - gap]
                    j -= gap
                # Put temp (the original seq[i]) in its correct location.
                seq[j] = temp

def main() -> None:
    seq = choices(population=range(1000), k=RAND_SEQUENCE_SIZE)
    print(f'{seq = }')
    print(f'{len(seq) = }')
    for name, gap_sequence in GAP_SEQUENCES.items():
        print(f'Shell sort using {name} gap sequence: {gap_sequence}')
        print(f'Time taken to sort 100 times: {timeit(lambda: shell_sort(seq.copy(), gap_sequence), number=100)} seconds')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Output:**

```
seq = [331, 799, 153, 700, 373, 38, 203, 535, 894, 500, 922, 939, 507, 506, 89, 40, 442, 108, 112, 359, 280, 946, 395, 708, 140, 435, 588, 306, 202, 23, 6, 189, 570, 600, 857, 949, 606, 617, 556, 863, 521, 776, 436, 801, 501, 588, 927, 279, 210, 72, 460, 52, 340, 632, 385, 965, 730, 360, 88, 216, 991, 520, 74, 112, 770, 853, 483, 787, 229, 812, 259, 349, 967, 227, 957, 728, 780, 51, 604, 748, 3, 679, 33, 488, 130, 203, 493, 471, 397, 53, 49, 172, 7, 306, 613, 519, 575, 64, 168, 161, 376, 903, 338, 800, 58, 729, 421, 238, 967, 294, 967, 218, 456, 823, 649, 569, 144, 103, 970, 780, 859, 719, 15, 536, 263, 917, 0, 54, 370, 703, 911, 518, 78, 41, 106, 452, 355, 571, 249, 58, 274, 327, 500, 341, 743, 536, 432, 799, 597, 681, 301, 856, 219, 63, 653, 680, 891, 725, 537, 673, 815, 504, 720, 573, 60, 91, 909, 892, 964, 119, 793, 540, 303, 538, 130, 717, 755, 968, 46, 229, 837, 398, 182, 303, 99, 808, 56, 780, 415, 33, 511, 771, 875, 593, 120, 727, 505, 905, 619, 295, 958, 566, 8, 291, 811, 529, 789, 523, 545, 5, 631, 28, 107, 292, 831, 657, 952, 239, 814, 862, 912, 2, 147, 750, 132, 528, 408, 916, 718, 261, 488, 621, 261, 963, 880, 625, 151, 982, 819, 749, 224, 572, 690, 766, 278, 417, 248, 987, 664, 515, 691, 940, 860, 172, 898, 321, 381, 662, 293, 354, 642, 219, 133, 133, 854, 162, 254, 816, 630, 21, 577, 486, 792, 731, 714, 581, 633, 794, 120, 386, 874, 177, 652, 159, 264, 414, 417, 730, 728, 716, 973, 688, 106, 345, 153, 909, 382, 505, 721, 363, 230, 588, 765, 340, 142, 549, 558, 189, 547, 728, 974, 468, 182, 255, 637, 317, 40, 775, 696, 135, 985, 884, 131, 797, 84, 89, 962, 810, 520, 843, 24, 400, 717, 834, 170, 681, 333, 68, 159, 688, 422, 198, 621, 386, 391, 839, 283, 167, 655, 314, 820, 432, 412, 181, 440, 864, 828, 217, 491, 593, 298, 885, 831, 535, 92, 305, 510, 90, 949, 461, 627, 851, 606, 280, 413, 624, 916, 16, 517, 700, 776, 323, 161, 329, 25, 868, 258, 97, 219, 620, 69, 24, 794, 981, 361, 691, 20, 90, 825, 442, 531, 562, 240, 0, 440, 418, 338, 526, 34, 230, 381, 598, 734, 925, 209, 231, 980, 122, 374, 752, 144, 105, 920, 780, 828, 948, 515, 443, 810, 81, 303, 751, 779, 516, 394, 455, 116, 448, 652, 293, 327, 367, 793, 47, 946, 653, 927, 910, 583, 845, 442, 989, 393, 490, 564, 54, 656, 689, 626, 531, 941, 575, 628, 865, 705, 219, 42, 19, 10, 155, 436, 319, 510, 520, 869, 101, 918, 170, 826, 146, 389, 200, 992, 404, 982, 889, 818, 684, 524, 642, 991, 973, 561, 104, 418, 207, 963, 192, 410, 33]
len(seq) = 500
Shell sort using CIURA_A102549 gap sequence: [701, 301, 132, 57, 23, 10, 4, 1]
Time taken to sort 100 times: 0.06717020808719099 seconds
Shell sort using KNUTH_A003462 gap sequence: [29524, 9841, 3280, 1093, 364, 121, 40, 13, 4, 1]
Time taken to sort 100 times: 0.34870366705581546 seconds
Shell sort using SPACED_OUT_PRIME_GAPS gap sequence: [30341, 10111, 3371, 1123, 373, 149, 53, 17, 5, 1]
Time taken to sort 100 times: 0.3563524999190122 seconds
Shell sort using SPACED_OUT_EVEN_GAPS gap sequence: [29160, 9720, 3240, 1080, 360, 120, 60, 30, 10, 1]
Time taken to sort 100 times: 0.38147866702638566 seconds
```